# How to add a resource to project using workflow in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

As the title says...

I've successfully got workflows working that create project tasks, so I have some idea how the workflow customization tools work.  But I'm struggling to see how I can (or even if I can) use a workflow to auto-magically add resources to the project (and then assign them to the project tasks I dynamically create.

Regarding which users/employees to add as resources, I imagine sorting out an appropriate clause shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, Resouces on a Project record are sublists.  If I am correct, then it is not possible via workflows.  There is a limitation with Workflows that they cannot work on record sublists.

You will have to do this via SuiteScript.

Comment: Thanks, I had an awful suspicion this was the case.